# What is the difference between 「なく」 and 「なしに」?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

I know there is an adjective 「関係ない」 which is basically a noun + ない, but I recently came across 「なしに」 in this sentence :

> 準備なしに発表した。

And I noticed that the に in なしに was making it act like an adverb. So I just wanted to know if I can say :

> 準備なく発表した。

And if yes, what is the difference between なしに and なく?

Comment: Maybe this could interest you : http://selftaughtjapanese.com/2015/09/16/japanese-grammar-the-word-%E7%84%A1%E3%81%97-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%97-nashi-and-related-terms/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 準備なく発表した。
>   is equal to
>   "準備なしに発表した。"

The difference is so subtle that I can't explain it.

Examples

> 許可{きょか}なく出発{しゅっぱつ}した＝許可なしに出発した (without permission)
>   十分なデータなく判断{はんだん}した＝十分なデータなしに判断した (without adequate data)
>   誰にも知られることなく立ち去った＝誰にも知られることなしに立ち去った (without someone knowing about ...)

Thus "名詞+なく" is equal to "名詞+なしに," but there are exceptions.

There is an idiom "お構{かま}いなしに(without any regard to ...)," but we don't say "お構{かま}いなく" as the same meaning.

Actually "お構いなく" has a different meaning.

> "How can I help you? (何かお困{こま}りですか？)"
>   "Thank you, but no thank you. (いえ、大丈夫です。お構{かま}いなく)"

Comment: Thanks! So なしに is not more polite than なく ? And if なく and なしに are the same, what about the difference between なしで and なく, and the difference between なしで and なしに ? I don't know if I should make a new post for this... anyway thanks